# C++ - Invalid delete from valgrind

Tags: c++, class, object, valgrind

I have a low level template class, and another class which contains a pointer to an instance of this class.  The code compiles correctly, but I run into the below error when running it through valgrind:

```
==2642== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2642==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:507)
==2642==    by 0x4125B4: List<std::string>::~List() (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
==2642==    by 0x411CB0: Obj3::~Obj3() (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
==2642==    by 0x410AC1: main (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
==2642==  Address 0x5a02878 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 88 alloc'd
==2642==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==2642==    by 0x4124FE: List<std::string>::List() (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
==2642==    by 0x411BC6: Obj3::Obj3(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string) (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
==2642==    by 0x41065A: main (in /home/alex/Documents/Documents/cpp/object_module/obj_test)
```

You can find the class files below, please note that I've stripped out code not relevant to memory assignment.

Here's the List class:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template <class T>
class List
{
  T *int_array;
  ...
  public:
    List() {int_array=new T[10];}
    ~List() {delete int_array;}
    ...
};
#endif
```

Here's the Obj3 class:

```
#ifndef OBJ3_H
#define OBJ3_H

#include <string>
#include "list.h"

class Obj3
{
    private:
        //A list of scenes
        List <std::string> *scene_list;
        ...
    public:
            //Constructors & Destructor
            Obj3() {scene_list = new List <std::string>;}
            ~Obj3() {delete scene_list;}
            ...
#endif
```

And, finally, the main method:

```
#include "obj3.h"

void print_obj_attributes(Obj3& obj)
{
std::cout << obj.get_name() << std::endl;
...
}

int main()
{
Obj3 obj2;
std::cout << "Object 2" << std::endl;
print_obj_attributes(obj2);
}
```

The entire program executes, and then the error is encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `delete[]` because you used `new[]` for `int_array`:

```
...
public:
  List() {int_array=new T[10];}
  ~List() {delete[] int_array;}
                 ~~
...
```

BTW: What you're doing is UB. $5.3.5/2 Delete [expr.delete] (emphasized by me):

> In the first alternative (**delete object**), the value of the operand of
>   delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a **non-array object**
>   created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject
>   (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not,
>   the behavior is **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you the clue: if you create an array you delete it with:

```
delete[] int_array;
```

What you currently have:

```
delete int_array;
```

Will only delete the pointer pointing to the head of the array.